# Why is my builder function executed twice?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check whether collection with this username and account type exists, it means I want to see if user is premium.

The output when app runs is:
ok
user
ok
model

Why does it print 'ok' twice and it looks like snapshot both has and hasn't any data?

Here is part of the code, if it doesn't say anything I will provide full class:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading
          ? Container(
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            )
          : StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
                  .where('account', isEqualTo: 'model')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                print('ok');
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  box.put('account', 'user');
                  print(box.get('account'));
                } else {
                  box.put('account', 'model');
                  print(box.get('account'));
                }
                return Container(...
```

Thank you in advance and maybe there is easiest way to see if collection with such data exists?

Comment: `isLoading` might have been toogle multiple times causing the function to run multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see this is working as intended. When your widget is first rendered, it starts loading the data for the `stream` from Firestore. At that point `snapshot.hasData` is still `false`, so it renders your widget with the `if` block.

Then when the data becomes available, the stream gets updated, and that triggers the widget to be rendered again. At this point, the `snapshot.hasData` is `true`, so it renders your widget with the `else` block.